# How to Selecting 500 rows to be processed in meantime get the total rows in that table

Tags: mysql

is there a way to select couple columns using a limit but in mean time get the total count of rows in that table

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM table where col3=0 limit 500
```

just like above. what to add to get the total of rows in the table

thank you

Comment: total count except where conditons?(col3=0)

Comment: thanks for responding. i don't understand mysql that much , so I really don't understand what you mean

Comment: if you want the count of rows in the table not count of rows with the col3=0, no way as far as i  know.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i just coded a counter in the program, i thought i'd ask see if  mysql may have any tricks...lol but thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you only need to use one column in the count

```sql
SELECT COUNT(col3) FROM table where col3=0
```

And here's a reference for more information  [MySQL COUNT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/)

Note, to keep it simple, you have to run two queries, this one for the **count** and yours for the **records**

Comment: i still need col1 and col2 results tho :)

Comment: you are counting the rows, the column is not relevant.  Because you are filtering on col3, its best to use col3 in the count.  have you tried it ?

Comment: SELECT col1,col2 FROM table where col3=0 limit 500     <<< i need all the data from col1 and col2 from the table limited to 500 records with a condition of col3 = 0 RESUTLS with total of records that are in that table.

Comment: If you put a limit then the maximum count will be 500.  The above will give you the total of the records in the table that have col3=0.  You have to run two queries, the first as you have it for the **records**, and this one for the **count**.

Comment: If this helped you should tick it

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks a precise problem statement.
My understanding of your question is as follows:

All of the following is necessary:

1. Need to get every row from the table, such that `col3=0`.
2. Need to get the total number of rows in the table (whether they satisfy `col3=0` or not).
3. Need to limit your result set to columns `col1`, `col2`, and have at most 500 rows.
4. Need to execute a single query, rather than two separate queries.

If this is correct interpretation of your question, then I would propose the following solution:

`SELECT col1,col2, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) AS total_rows FROM table where col3=0 limit 500`

Such query would produce result where at most 500 rows from your table satisfy the condition `col3=0` are present alongside total_rows, which tells the number of all the rows in the table.

Example CSV of the result:

```
clo1,col2,total_rows
a,b,1000
c,d,1000
d,e,1000
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [found_rows()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

> The SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS query modifier and accompanying FOUND_ROWS() function are deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17; expect them to be removed in a future version of MySQL. As a replacement, considering executing your query with LIMIT, and then a second query with COUNT(*) and without LIMIT to determine whether there are additional rows

> instead of these queries:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

> Use these queries instead:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100;
```

> COUNT(*) is subject to certain optimizations. SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS causes some optimizations to be disabled.

you can check these questions

[how-to-get-number-of-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906690/mysql-what-is-the-row-count-information-function-for-select)

[mysql-what-is-the-row-count-information-function-for-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906690/mysql-what-is-the-row-count-information-function-for-select)